# React-native How to hide keyboard when datepicker is opened

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm creating dynamically fields, one of them is DatePicker

```
const birthDateField = {
    type: 'birthDate',
    key: 'birthDate',
    label: 'Date of Birth',
    isRequired: true,
    editable: false,
    selectTextOnFocus: false,
    get fieldValue() {
        return !!this.value ? moment(this.value).format('DD MMM YYYY') : null;
    }
};
```

Once user presses on datepicker native keyboard is opened. They can see it after datepicker is closed. How to prevent from opening keyboard?

I'm using react-native and DatePickerAndroid, DatePickerIOS

Answer (score 3):

That's all that you have to do when **Datepicker** is opened:

```js
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

// Hide that keyboard!
Keyboard.dismiss()
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9925

Check the link for more info. Cheers

Comment: It doesn’t work for ios, do have any idea? Thank you